# jodatime compatiblility issue with hibernate 5

Tags: hibernate, jodatime, localdate

I am having trouble to use jodatime with hibernate 5 & java 8.

I am migrating a big application from spring4/hibernate4/java7 to spring5/hibernate5/java8.

**Spring 5.0.5.RELEASE

Hibernate 5.2.16.Final**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
    <artifactId>usertype.jodatime</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Entity Bean

```
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
@Column(name="START_DATE")
private org.joda.time.LocalDate startDate;
```

Due to the exsitging codes, I cannot use java8 time library. I've tried but it ended up huge change that I could manage.

Anyone has experience with this?

This is the error that I am getting on startup.

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeGet(CustomType.java:119)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:82)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2854)
```

Comment: Did find a way to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your version of org.jadira.usertype is too old for this version of Hibernate. You need at least 5.0.0.GA or 6.0.0.1.GA.